# Lucene.Net: Searching multiple date/date-range in same document

Tags: lucene.net, lucene

I have an event which happens on multiple dates (like every 5th of month for the next 6 months). If a user searches for events for next 45 days on 4th than he should get above event, but for queries like next 7 days on 6th should not return above event.

I have create document for event and added multiple date filed on same document.

```
var event1 = new Document();
event1.Add(new Field("Id", "2", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
event1.Add(new Field("Name", "Ford", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
event1.Add(new Field("Desc", "Focus", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
event1.Add(new NumericField("Date", (int)new DateTime(2012, 6, 05).Subtract(dt).TotalMinutes, Field.Store.YES, true));
event1.Add(new NumericField("Date", (int)new DateTime(2012, 7, 05).Subtract(dt).TotalMinutes, Field.Store.YES, true));
event1.Add(new NumericField("Date", (int)new DateTime(2012, 8, 05).Subtract(dt).TotalMinutes, Field.Store.YES, true));
```

The idea is that if I search on a specific date or date-range it should work. But once I try to write this document, it throws an NullReferenceException.

```
 Directory directory = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\LuceneIndex"));
 Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29);

 var writer = new IndexWriter(directory, true, analyzer, true);
 writer.AddDocument(event1);
```

I am not sure how to perform these type of searches.

**Update 1:** 
writer.AddDocument(event1); causing the null reference,

**Update 2:**

```
at Lucene.Net.Store.IndexOutput.WriteString(String s)
at Lucene.Net.Index.FieldsWriter.WriteField(FieldInfo fi, Fieldable field)
at Lucene.Net.Index.StoredFieldsWriterPerThread.AddField(Fieldable field, FieldInfo fieldInfo)
at Lucene.Net.Index.DocFieldProcessorPerThread.ProcessDocument()
at Lucene.Net.Index.DocumentsWriter.UpdateDocument(Document doc, Analyzer analyzer, Term delTerm)
at Lucene.Net.Index.DocumentsWriter.AddDocument(Document doc, Analyzer analyzer)
at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.AddDocument(Document doc, Analyzer analyzer)
at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.AddDocument(Document doc)
at luceneSearch.Program.Main(String[] args) in
```

Comment: What line causes a null reference exception?

Comment: writer.AddDocument(event1); causing the null reference,

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on that line, is writer null?

Comment: Did you mean to write `event1.Add(...)` instead of `fordFocus.Add(...)` ?

Answer (score 0):

The [NumericField constructor](https://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/document/NumericField.html) accepts a precisionStep, not the actual value. The correct usage requires you to call [SetIntValue](https://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/document/NumericField.html#setIntValue%28int%29) (or any of the other set*Value methods).

```
event1.Add(new NumericField("Date", Field.Store.YES, true)
             .SetIntValue((int)new DateTime(2012, 6, 05).Subtract(dt).TotalMinutes));
event1.Add(new NumericField("Date", Field.Store.YES, true)
             .SetIntValue((int)new DateTime(2012, 7, 05).Subtract(dt).TotalMinutes));
event1.Add(new NumericField("Date", Field.Store.YES, true)
             .SetIntValue((int)new DateTime(2012, 8, 05).Subtract(dt).TotalMinutes));
```

The exception occurs because `NumericField.StringValue()` returns null if no value is set.